# Erro android studio, error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'

Tags: java, android

Alguém saberia qual é esse erro:

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.

Comment: Por favor, complete sua pergunta.

Comment: Em qual momento ele ocorre?  Qual é a minSdkVersion da sua aplicação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em algum momento você referencia o tema Holo, parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
mas pra usá-lo é necessário definir o API level para 11 em seu manifest.
Você também deve colocar o style.xml que faz uso do holo dentro da pasta values-11.

Veja isto: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295018/error-error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-give

Answer (score 1):

Seria melhor se postasse seu Styles.xml aqui. 
Provavelmente é o nível de sua API está abaixo de 11, o tema Holo só está disponível a partir da API 11.

Aumente o nível de sua API ou retire o "Holo".

```
"android:Theme.Light"
```